# error in calculating minutes from timedelta objects in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I tried calculating minutes by subtracting two columns. But an error shows up which is " ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number".
However, I tried similar operation on two different columns but it worked.

I tried calculating arr_delay, but there was no error. But error came up when I tried calculating dep_delay.

```
data['arr_delay'] = (pd.to_timedelta(data.ATA) - pd.to_timedelta(data.STA)).dt.total_seconds()/60
data['dep_delay'] = (pd.to_timedelta(data.ATD) - pd.to_timedelta(data.STD)).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

I was able to calculate arr_delay. But an error came up while calculating dep_delay which is :-" ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number "

[image: Data Sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there are some `bad` values in some column, so use parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert these values to `NaT`:

```
data['dep_delay'] = (pd.to_timedelta(data.ATD, errors='coerce') - 
                     pd.to_timedelta(data.STD, errors='coerce')).dt.total_seconds()/60
```